# C# assigning a derived class to a base class variable with generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a set of classes and interfaces which have a relatively simple hierarchy, however having things inherit and then having a variable which accepts the base class is not working well. I think the problem is that my dynamic types MUST be `where : class` and not `where : IEntity` because these types are used in functions which I have no ability to change.

```
public interface IB<X, Y> 
    where X : class, IEntity 
    where Y : class, IEntity
{
    ...
}

public abstract class A
{
    ...
}

public abstract class B<X, Y> : A, IB<X, Y> 
    where X : class, IEntity 
    where Y : class, IEntity
{
    ...
}

public interface IEntity
{
    ...
}

public class Entity1 : IEntity
{
    ...
}

public class Entity2 : IEntity
{
    ...
}

public class C : B<Entity1, Entity2>, IB<Entity1, Entity2>
{
   ...
}
```

And then, attempting to use all this in a function...

```
C c = new C();
IB<IEntity, IEntity> ib = c;
```

Cannot implicityly or explicity cast this.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface is not covariantly valid. That is to say,

`IB<IEntity, IEntity>` and `IB<Entity1, Entity2>` are not the same thing. To fix this, you can use the `out` keyword on the type parameters in the interface definition

```
public interface IB<out X, out Y> where X : class where Y : class
```

As a secondary point, you need to cascade your constraints to class B

```
public abstract class B<X, Y> : A, IB<X, Y> where X : class where Y : class
```

With these changes in place, your assignment of C into ib is legal.

```
C c = new C(); 
IB<IEntity, IEntity> ib = c;
```

(And as Davy8 correctly points out in the comments, this interface covariance feature requires C# 4+.)

Comment: Might always want to mention that this requires C#4 (and .NET 4.0?)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the definition of `class B` as follows:

```
public abstract class B<X, Y> : A, IB<X, Y> where X : class where Y : class 
{
    ...
}
```

Constraints have to be specified throughout the inheritance chain.